# Add different image as background in each section in grouped table view in iphone applications

Tags: iphone

I want to create an Iphone application using Grouped Table View. I created the Grouped Table View. My Grouped Table View having the three section. I want to add different images as background for each section in grouped table view.

If I use the following code in each section, the total view displayed in same image.

```
    NSString *backgroundPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"background" ofType:@"jpg"];

    UIImage *backgroundImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:backgroundPath];

    UIColor *backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:backgroundImage];

    tableView.backgroundColor = backgroundColor; 

    [backgroundColor release];
```

Comment: I think there is no way you can do that:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
- (void) tableView: (UITableView *) tableView willDisplayCell: (UITableViewCell *) cell forRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *) indexPath {
    UIColor * color;

    switch (indexPath.section) {
        case 0:
            color = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage: [UIImage imageNamed: @"...0"]]; break;
        case 1:
            color = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage: [UIImage imageNamed: @"...1"]]; break;
        case 2:
            color = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage: [UIImage imageNamed: @"...2"]]; break;
        default:
            color = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage: [UIImage imageNamed: @"..."]]; break;
            break;
    }

    cell.backgroundColor = color;
}
```

Replace `...` and `...X` with the images you want to use. Add more or remove some `case`s to achieve the right number of sections.

Comment: Okay. After I read your answer, I wasn't sure if you wanted to change the cell's background or the table's background, but I'm glad it worked out for you.